# Problem installing github-cli-2.20.2-r0 on Alpine Linux v3.17 running on WSL-2

Tags: github, apk

I am trying to install the github-cli-2.20.2-r0 on Alpine Linux v3.17 running on WSL-2

I have the following repositories on my system:

```
cat /etc/apk/repositories
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/main
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/latest-stable/community
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/main
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/community
http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing
```

I did an apk search for the githb cli

```
    apk search github
        foliate-2.6.4-r1
        github-cli-2.20.2-r0
        github-cli-zsh-completion-2.20.2-r0
        py3-pygithub-1.57-r0
        github-cli-bash-completion-2.20.2-r0
        tootle-1.0-r2
        github-cli-doc-2.20.2-r0
```

Then tried an install

```
    sudo apk add github-cli-2.20.2-r0
        ERROR: unable to select packages:
          github-cli-2.20.2-r0 (no such package):
            required by: world[github-cli-2.20.2-r0]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the version worked for me:

> sudo apk add github-cli